# Qual a maneira correta de consumir BLOBs via JAVASCRIPTS, HTML5, etc?

Tags: javascript, servlet, blob, google-app-engine

Eu estou utilizando BLOBSTORE do Google App Engine. Ja tenho algumas imagens salvas no servidor agora gostaria de consumí-las via browser (HTML5, JAVASCRIPT etc...) Acontece que eu tenho apenas o link que aparentemente não é da imagem propriamente dita, como segue:

https://filiperebollo1986.appspot.com/serve?blob-key=AMIfv967H0sWgJttreCFsuGZ57JmaXCkhFPC4QoHcPPxLBN2JhGkOGsY34rdD4ebvqNtdYfTmf_utULqUjdP_9mkjJQ91jkwkcDMlxlU7PZwrC-r0W-eIa3r8YaTWPKd7hAzuTcftyiUg8Ho2k9g1k4JV4Yx2MzdTwe_HeCHKGCvxnH3sm_WWN0

Note que não há a extensão no URL...

Qual a maneira correta de consumir esses blobs no browser? Posso simplesmente utilizar este URL no parâmetro SRC da IMG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim pode usar com a tag img do HTML5, segue o exemplo:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://filiperebollo1986.appspot.com/serve?blob-key=AMIfv967H0sWgJttreCFsuGZ57JmaXCkhFPC4QoHcPPxLBN2JhGkOGsY34rdD4ebvqNtdYfTmf_utULqUjdP_9mkjJQ91jkwkcDMlxlU7PZwrC-r0W-eIa3r8YaTWPKd7hAzuTcftyiUg8Ho2k9g1k4JV4Yx2MzdTwe_HeCHKGCvxnH3sm_WWN0" />
</div>
```

Mas se tratando de boas praticas segue algumas considerações:
Existem algumas boas praticas a serem seguidas quando o assunto é servir imagens da web, a maioria consiste em otimizar a própria imagem para diminuir seu peso, e assim diminuindo seu tamanho o que resultaria em um menor tempo para o usuário conseguir visualizar a mesma no seu site, existe um guia do proprio google em pt-br para ensinar sobre o assunto, vou estar deixando o link no final da resposta, alem disso também é sempre indicado o uso de um serviço de CDN para servir as imagens e também utilizar estrategias de cache.

link do guia de otimização: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization?hl=pt-br

Comment: link do jsfidle, com um exemplo "executavel" https://jsfiddle.net/brz4g3c1/

Comment: Mas essa é a melhor prática? Qual seria a melhor maneira de consumir esses blobs? Nao terei problemas de performance usando esse url diretamente? Pq eu percebo que demora um pouco pra carregar no browser..

Comment: alterei a resposta para contemplar essa pergunta, beleza?

Comment: Não estou vendo a alteração apenas as tags HTML conforme vc tinha respondido no começo..

Comment: Opa Felipe, verifique agora.

Comment: Você quer dizer que o URL gerado performa tanto quanto um URL do tipo *.jpeg?

Comment: Sim, portanto que o seu servidor enviei o content-type da sua imagem na response, não faz diferença nenhuma, agora quanto ao melhor tipo de extensão a ser utilizado é outra historia, isso é bem detalhado nesse guia que eu coloquei, no caso da sua imagem, ela está enviando o conten-type image/png, em geral o formato que mais performa e tem alta compatibilidade com os browser é o JPEG, porem a qualidade dele é menor.

Comment: Consegui esclarecer suas duvidas?

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada Felipe, que bom que consegui ajudar, bons estudos, só não esqueça de priorizar os comentários relevantes, marcar a resposta como util e a pergunta como resolvida, para os outros usuários conseguirem visualizar melhor, :)

Comment: No meu backend eu criei um Serve.java além de upload...Qual a necessidade de utilizá-lo se eu posso consumir direto pelo URL? E como eu consigo utilizá-lo via browser, JAVASCRIPT, HTML5..

public class Serve extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException {
            BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
            blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
        }
}

Comment: Ao meu ver dada as suas restrições, não vejo nenhum motivo para você não utilizar a URL diretamente, lembre-se só de fazer upload das imagens otimizadas para o seu serviço do google se você estiver focando em performance.